# WORD VBA Count Word Occurrences

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have a code below that is already working. However i need to simplify the code even further. The code i have below counts the word occurrences in a document. The code is as follows:

```
Option Base 1

Sub arrangepara()
Dim r As Range

Set r = activedocument.Range
If (r.Characters.Last.text = vbCr) Then r.End = r.End - 1
sortpara r
End Sub

Function sortpara(r As Range)
Dim sWrd As String
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim N As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, WordNum As Integer
N = r.Words.count
ReDim Freq(N) As Integer
ReDim Words(N) As String
Dim temp As String

i = 1
WordNum = 0
Do While r.Find.Execute(findtext:="<*>", MatchWildcards:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
   If i = N Then Exit Do
        Found = False
        For j = 1 To WordNum
               If Words(j) = r.text Then
                   Freq(j) = Freq(j) + 1
                   Found = True
                   Exit For
               End If
        Next j
        If Not Found Then
            WordNum = WordNum + 1
            Words(WordNum) = r.text
            Freq(WordNum) = 1
        End If
   i = i + 1
Loop

Set r = activedocument.Range
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
r.InsertParagraphBefore
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

r.InsertAfter "Occurrence List:"
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
r.InsertParagraphBefore
r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd


For j = 1 To WordNum
    r.InsertAfter Words(j) & " (" & Freq(j) & ")" & vbCr
Next j

r.Select
Selection.sort SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending
r.Font.Color = wdColorAqua

End Function
```

I need to simply this part and i dont know how. Are there any good samaritans out there that can simplify the codes for me? Thanks much! Below is what i need to simplify:

```
Do While r.Find.Execute(findtext:="<*>", MatchWildcards:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
   If i = N Then Exit Do
        Found = False
        For j = 1 To WordNum
               If Words(j) = r.text Then
                   Freq(j) = Freq(j) + 1
                   Found = True
                   Exit For
               End If
        Next j
        If Not Found Then
            WordNum = WordNum + 1
            Words(WordNum) = r.text
            Freq(WordNum) = 1
        End If
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by "simplify" you mean "improve performance", as I suspect this is going to be horrendously slow.

I would avoid getting all the words by using Find. Instead of:

```
Do While r.Find.Execute(findtext:="<*>", MatchWildcards:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
   ...
Loop
```

I think you should use:

```
Dim w as Word
For each w In ActiveDocument.Words
   ...
Next
```