# Getting count of characters WITHOUT spaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-office, office-addins

I am writing an Office Add-In in C#. 
I am trying to get the number of characters **without** spaces from a Word document with the `WdBuiltInProperty`. However, the conversion to `long` does not work.

The error message is:

> *The COM Object of Type "System._ComObject" can not be converted to "System.IConvertible"*

Here is my code snippet of `thisAddIn.cs` so far:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
// ...
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  public void Calc()
  {
    Word.Document doc = this.Application.ActiveDocument ;
    long c=doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties[Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyCharacters];
    // ^^^ Error ^^^
  }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How can the conversion be done properly?

and/or

2. Is there another way to get the number of characters **without** spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `BuiltInDocumentProperties`, use `Characters` which has a `Count` property.

`long c = doc.Characters.Count;`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.characters.count.aspx

**EDIT** (from a [VBA example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126690/how-to-iterate-through-text-in-the-word-document-by-vb-macro)):

```
Sub CountChars()
    Dim iCount(57) As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim iTotal As Integer
    Dim iAsc As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    iTotal = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters.Count

    For x = 1 To iTotal
        iAsc = Asc(ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(x))
        If iAsc >= 65 And iAsc <= 122 Then
        iCount(iAsc - 65) = iCount(iAsc - 65) + 1
        End If
    Next x
    For x = 0 To 57
        Debug.Print x, iCount(x)
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, no, this counts **including** spaces, but I need the count **without** spaces.

Comment: I found this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17126907/3854195) that explains how to count a specific character.  You could use it to count the number of spaces and then subtract that from the total, or alternatively, count individual characters as you iterate and exclude from the count if it's a space.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Indeed, if I find no other solution, I will take this approach. Simply looping through the text and counting.

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties[Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyCharacters].Value;
```

Result from `BuiltInDocumentProperties[]` is `Office.DocumentProperty` (can be found by inspecting the Locals window in the Word VBA editor), and it's default `.Value` property contains the number.
It works without `.Value` in VBA, because VBA has different default value assignment (`Let`), and separate and object reference assignment with `Set`. Also, `Long` type in VBA is `Int32` in .NET