# Word occurences in VBA: how to speed up

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to write a MS Word macro to count occurence of every word within a given document and print out the list like .
I did the macro and it works, but it is so sloooow, it takes several hours to get results for a document of 60000 words. 
Could you please give me some advices/suggestions on how to make the macro run faster?

(I checked a similar question here [WORD VBA Count Word Occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645762/word-vba-count-word-occurrences) but still don't get it how to speed up and need my macro to be reviewed). Thank you.

```
Private Type WordStatData
    WordText As String
    WordCount As Integer
End Type

Option Base 1
'Check if the word is valid

Private Function IsValidWord(SomeString As String) As Boolean
    Dim Retval As Boolean
    Retval = True
    If Not (InStr(SomeString, " ") = 0) Then Retval = False
    If Not (InStr(SomeString, ".") = 0) Then Retval = False
    If Not (InStr(SomeString, ",") = 0) Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "0") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "1") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "2") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "3") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "4") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "5") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "6") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "7") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "8") = 0 Then Retval = False
    If Not InStr(SomeString, "9") = 0 Then Retval = False
    IsValidWord = Retval
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SpanishLCID = 3082 'The source text is in Spanish
    ListBox1.Clear
    Dim WordsTotal As Long
    WordsTotal = ActiveDocument.Words.Count
    TextBox1.Text = Str(WordsTotal)
    Dim Wordfound As Boolean
    Dim NewWord As String
    Dim MyData() As WordStatData
    ReDim Preserve MyData(1)
    NewWord = ""
    For i = 1 To WordsTotal
        NewWord = Trim(StrConv(Trim(ActiveDocument.Words(i)), vbLowerCase, SpanishLCID))
        'Check if the word is in the list
        If IsValidWord(NewWord) Then
            Wordfound = False
            For j = 1 To UBound(MyData)
                If StrComp(MyData(j).WordText, NewWord) = 0 Then
                    Wordfound = True: Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If Wordfound Then
                MyData(j).WordCount = MyData(j).WordCount + 1
            Else
                ReDim Preserve MyData(UBound(MyData) + 1)
                MyData(UBound(MyData)).WordText = NewWord
                MyData(UBound(MyData)).WordCount = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'Printing out the word list
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyData)
        ListBox1.AddItem (MyData(i).WordText & "=" & Str(MyData(i).WordCount))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I will take a look, but a quick fix you could exit the IsValidWord once its been set to false, as youre checking space to 9 each time.

Comment: Thanks, I should have implemented that..

Comment: Loop over all of the words in the document, adding them to a Scripting Dictionary: each time you find a new word, increment the value for that "key".   You can then check your list against the Dictionary to find the count for each word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (**Tools** -> **References...**). Then use the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const SpanishLCID = 3082
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, word As Variant, fixedWord As String
    Dim key As Variant

    dict.CompareMode = SpanishLCID
    For Each word In ActiveDocument.Words
        fixedWord = Trim(StrConv(Trim(word), vbLowerCase, SpanishLCID))
        If Not dict.Exists(fixedWord) Then
            dict(fixedWord) = 1
        Else
            dict(fixedWord) = dict(fixedWord) + 1
        End If
    Next

    ListBox1.Clear
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        ListBox1.AddItem key & "=" & dict(key)
    Next
End Sub
```

NB. Word treats each punctuation symbol or paragraph as a new word. It may be advisable to specify another Dictionary or Collection with the strings that shouldn't be added to the dictionary, and test for those strings using `.Exists` before adding to the dictionary.

---

A more concise version of `IsValidWord` without regular expressions:

```
Function IsValidWord(s As String) As Boolean
    Const validChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim i As Integer, char As String * 1
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        char = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If InStr(1, validChars, char, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Next
    IsValidWord = True
End Function
```

and using [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/111794) (add a reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5**):

```
Dim regex As RegExp
Function IsValidWord2(s As String) As Boolean
    If regex Is Nothing Then
        Set regex = New RegExp
        regex.Pattern = "[^a-z]"
        regex.IgnoreCase = True
    End If
    IsValidWord2 = Not regex.Test(s)
End Function
```

and using regular expressions with replacement:

```
Function GetValidWord(s As String) As String
    'GetValidWord("Introduction.......3") will return "Introduction"
    If regex2 Is Nothing Then
        Set regex2 = New RegExp
        regex2.Pattern = "[^a-z]"
        regex2.Global = True
        regex2.IgnoreCase = True
    End If
    GetValidWord = regex2.Replace(s, "")
End Function
```

and you would use it as follows:

```
    For Each word In ActiveDocument.Words
        fixedWord = Trim(StrConv(Trim(word), vbLowerCase, SpanishLCID))
        fixedWord = GetValidWord(fixedWord)
        If Not dict.Exists(fixedWord) Then
```

NB: You might combine the language conversion and `Trim` into `GetValidWord`.

Comment: Thank you! It does the job very fast!

Comment: However I've added the IsValidWord() function to avoid wrong words to beadded and counted (do not know how to predict all possible versions of wrong words to add into a special dictionary to filter them out, e.g. "Introduction.....................................3", or some Unicode strings that looks like just a whitespace)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Regular Expressions in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/4600127) to specify valid words?